# Can a DNS (BIND) server be set to provide name resolution for LAN machines that have no FQDN?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

All machines on the LAN are named `<machine_name>.local`. Can I set up a DNS (BIND) server for my LAN's machines that will provide name resolution?

For instance, if the DHCP (or `/etc/hosts`) is setting the following:

```
192.168.1.10   sample.local
```

Then the DNS will know how to do a name resolution between `192.168.1.10` and `sample.local` (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is nothing special about it. The name `sample.local` is a perfectly normal FQDN, except that `local` is reserved for local use.

The bind DNS server need this information in zone files, it will not read host lists from `/etc/hosts`. If you want a simple DNS server that can get the host lists from `/etc/hosts`, look at dnsmasq.